# Year 2038 bug, can I deviate from the OpenPGP RFC?

Tags: rfc, openpgp, year2038

The [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880), a document that describes the OpenPGP cryptography standard, finds its roots in [RFC 2440](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2440), published in 1998 (that's *sixteen years ago*, supposedly before 64-bit systems emerged). Both specifications tell the same thing about how timestamps are handled:

> *[3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#page-10). Time Fields*
>
> A time field is an unsigned four-octet number containing the number
> of seconds elapsed since midnight, 1 January 1970 UTC.

**Should one try to follow this RFC as closely as possible** (and, here, face a sweet [year 2038 bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) one day)? Is it "risky" for a developer not to follow parts of standards/specifications/RFCs (especially when it comes to cryptography), when they are seen as potentially obsolete already?

I am a bit afraid of asking because the question sounds silly, but if I "implement RFC 4880" but in my own way, it is not the official thing any more. So, *what is the best thing a developer should do against what she sees as "obsolete" parts of specifications?* Nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: I think the example in your question is wrong. *RFC4880* uses an **unsigned** 32-bit integer. The y2k38 problem is a problem for **signed** 32-bit integers. According to Wikipedia, unsigned 32-bit integers work until the year 2106. A little more time.

To answer your question:
I think the best way is to get in contact with the RFC working group / the authors of the RFC and tell them about the obsolescence. Maybe, a follow-up RFC will fix that issue.

For your example, I think you can refrain from contacting the OpenPGP WG. I think, until 2106 there will be a lot of updates and I suspect V5 keys to have 8-octet time fields.